# Синонимизировать и объединить [navigation-drawer] и [android-navigation-drawer]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Все вопросы по [navigation-drawer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigation-drawer) и [android-navigation-drawer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-navigation-drawer) в контексте Android. Есть [один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigation-drawer+-android) по ios, но там это не название компонента из SDK.

Предлагаю [android-navigation-drawer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-navigation-drawer) сделать основной и объединить с [navigation-drawer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/navigation-drawer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метки объединены и синонимизированы.